# Eclipse open resource search without regex

Tags: java, eclipse

My question is whether there is a plugin for eclipse to improve the open resource dialog.

My biggest issue is that when searching for something like "AppInitConextFactoryProvider"

If I don't remember the App Init stuff I need to search `*FactoryProvider`, I even can't search for `*FP`, only `*F*P` will work.

I see the behavior in editors like SublimeText and VisualCode and they work very good. Is there something equivalent for Eclipse?

Comment: Interesting. What does work (although is not what you are asking about) is typing in `AICFP`. Somehow `*CFP` works differently.